# Inserting a new node at the beginning of a linked list in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

The struct looks like this:

```
typedef char AirportCode [4];
typedef struct node {
   AirportCode airport;
   struct node *next;
}Node;
```

My function looks like this:

```
void insertFirst(AirportCode code, Node **listPtr){
   Node *Holder = *listPtr;
   Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
   if (*listPtr == NULL){
    (*listPtr)->airport = code;
    (*listPtr)->next = NULL; }

   else{
    *listPtr = newNode;
    newNode->airport = code;
    newNode->next = holder; }
}
```

The error message is:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type 'AirportCode' from type 'char *'
```

This error message is on both of the lines where I assign the code values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216607/inserting-new-node have look @ this

Comment: also, dont double post

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't assign arrays in `C`. You can only initialize them. Also, you can't pass an array to a function - what actually gets passed is a pointer to the first element of the array.  The following statement

```
typedef char AirportCode[4];
```

defines a type `AirportCode` of type `char[4]` - an array of `4` characters. In your function `insertFirst`, you are assigning `code` which is of type `char *` to `(*listPtr)->airport` which is of type `AirportCode` or `char[4]`. These two are incompatible types and hence you are getting the error.

Since you can't pass an array to a function, what you should do is pass a pointer to the first element of the array and the array length as well. Then copy the array to the corresponding member of the structure.

The below three declarations are exactly the same. The array parameter in the function is actually a pointer to a character.

```
void insertFirst(AirportCode code, Node **listPtr);
void insertFirst(char code[4], Node **listPtr);
void insertFirst(char *code, Node **listPtr);
```

Also, you should not cast the result of `malloc`. Don't let the `typedef` clutter the namespace and cause confusion. You are better off without it in this case. If the `if` condition `*listPtr == NULL` is `true`, then you are dereferencing the null pointer in the block which is  obviously an error.

```
if(*listPtr == NULL) {
    // the below statements dereference the null pointer 
    // which is an error and would cause program crash 
    // due to segfault.

    (*listPtr)->airport = code; 
    (*listPtr)->next = NULL;     
}
```

From your `else` block, I assume you are trying to add a new node at the beginning of the linked list. I suggest the following changes (thanks to Jonathan Leffler).

```
typedef struct node {
   char airport[4];  // no typedef. explicit array declaration.
   struct node *next;
} Node;

void insertFirst(char *code, Node **listPtr) {
    Node *oldHead = *listPtr;
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if(newNode == NULL) {  // check for NULL
        printf("Not enough memory to allocate\n");
        return;
    }

    // if the struct member code is a string, then use strncpy to 
    // guard against buffer overrun, else use memcpy to copy
    // code to airport. this is assuming that the buffer pointed
    // to by code is never smaller than sizeof newNode->airport

    memcpy(newNode->airport, code, sizeof newNode->airport); 
    newNode->next = oldHead;

    *listPtr = newNode;  // make listPtr point to the new head
}
```

Comment: I think it might be better to use `strcpy()` or `memmove()` or `memcpy()` than to write the loop out long-hand (twice).  It isn't clear why you copy the new data over the old first node, rather than the new node.  If you look carefully, you can reduce the duplicated code a lot more.  See also [Inserting node into first place — C programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212729/inserting-node-into-first-place-c-programming/22212852#22212852).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, I updated my answer. One glaring mistake I overlooked was OP's `if` block dereferencing the null pointer. Now, hopefully I have removed code repetition.

Comment: Better…but the nitpicker is here :(  (1) Does the length include the terminal null? (2) Should you check that the length fits in the space available? (Since airport codes are currently limited to three letters, there's barely any reason to do other than copy `sizeof(newNode->airport)` bytes and you could drop the length parameter.) (3) Since you assign `*listPtr` in both the `if` and the `else`, you should do it outside the conditional, which leaves you with something to do only if `*listPtr != NULL`. (You have a case-sensitivity problem with your `Holder` vs `holder`.)  _[…Continued…]_

Comment: _[…Continuation…]_ Also, you could simply assign `newNode->next = holder` because you assign null if `holder` is null, and you assign the value of `holder` if `holder` is not null, which is the same as assigning the value of `holder`, isn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks a ton :) I like code nitpicking. It always only helps improve for better. Please have a look now.

Comment: Looks good now.  The only conditional is for the out of memory test; that is pretty much unavoidable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for guiding me there :) It's amazing how the code became shorter, cleaner and efficient as well. Totally thrilling.

Answer (score 0):

the basics goes like this

`int a=10,b;`

`b=a`

Above `works Fine`

the same thing for array

```
int a[]={1,2,3};

int b[3]

b=a; ---> this wrong way
```

`correct way is`

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
   b[i]=a[i];
}

 OR

strcpy(b,a);

char a[4],b[4];
 gets(a);
 b=a;----->wrong assigning

 correct way
 strcpy(b,a);
```

For more details find [Inserting New Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216607/inserting-new-node)