# Inserting New Node

Tags: c, linked-list

Here is a function of a program I'm writing to get more familiar with nodes.

It creates a new node and inserts the information into the code field and then points to the existing first node. Then assigns the head to the newly created node;

Unfortunately it's giving me a incompatible types for new_node->location = code;

```
typedef char LibraryCode[4];

typedef struct node {
    LibraryCode location;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

void insertFirstNode(LibraryCode code, Node **listPtr) {
    Node *new_node;
    new_node=malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_node->location = code;
    new_node->next = *listPtr;
    *listPtr = new_node;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LibraryCode` is `typdef`ed as a `char [4]`. You can't just assign one array to another, you'll need to `memcpy` or `strcpy` the data from one array to the other.

A simpler example of what's going on:

```
void foo() {
   char a[4];
   char b[4];
   a = b;
}
```

Compiling this gives the error:

```
In function ‘foo’:
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[4]’ from type ‘char *’
   a = b;
     ^
```

You can see that you're actually trying to assign a pointer to the array, which are incompatible types.

---

The `typedef char LibraryCode[4];` is probably not a good idea anyway. If you're going to keep a fixed-size buffer for the string in your node, then I would just ditch the `typedef` so it's clear what you're doing.  Also, I would never pass a `char [4]` *by value* to a function. For strings, pass a `const char*`.